# Is there any way to import Marmoset toolbag materials to Blender?

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor

I have a problem, I want to import a model in a Marmoset Toolbag scene into Blender. MarmoSet can export models to FBX and it is working great, except the textures. In the Principled BSDF node the metallic slider is set to 1 and specular to 2, which makes it a mirror, but when I make it lower it  looks like PS2 textures. While the materials look beautiful in Marmoset.. Is there any way to change this? Or import a .tbmat file to see if that works, thanks for helping, here are screenshots of marmoset, blender and node editor.
@Duarte Farrajota Ramos I dont get what you mean, I need to import Marmoset into Blender instead of other way around sorry if i dont understand
[image: Blender]

[image: Marmoset]

Comment: Does the duplicate explain your problem?

Comment: @Leander No, maybe i dont get it. Can you please explain?

Comment: I cast a reopen vote, since I feel the same way. Perhaps @Duarte can explain why he closed it. (I'm not sure if pinging works for close voters.)

Comment: @Robert, it looks like you are using the diffuse map for multiple inputs, it should only be supplying color data to the principled BSDF node, roughnesss is generalyl supplied by a greyscale roughness map in blender. Additionally, your normal map node has no actual texture data input, this will not give you the desired result. I cant explore the process directly as I do not own marmoset, but you will want to research how to set up PBR materials with blender's principled BSDF node.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck may help, this gives an overview of the way the principled BSDF node works in blender. Skip to about 30 minutes and the presenter starts applying "texture maps" to the principled node. I recommend watching the whole video at least once if you plan to use blender a lot. The video is slightly old, but the information is all good.