# TBSCENE extension

Tags: import, obj

I stumbled upon a 3D model that has this .tbscene extension file. In general, the folder with the model has an .obj file and a .mtl file. The thing is .mtl file doesn't specify any texture files, so when I import the .obj file into blender the model is just grey with a default material. But that weird .tbscene file has all the references to Normal Map file, Gloss Map file etc. I don't know how to use it so blender know what the heck is going on. Need help

Comment: According to Google that's a "Marmoset Toolbag" file. The only information mentioning Marmoset here is [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146268/is-there-any-way-to-import-marmoset-toolbag-materials-to-blender)  which is 3 years old and doesn't mention that file extension at all.